# What happened to Ghost?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Is Jon Snow's direwolf Ghost dead? Do we know  what happend to him in *Game of Thrones* S08E03 after he ran along with the Dothraki into the dead horde?

Comment: As the answer proves, *maybe* some of these questions could just wait for another week?

Comment: Ok thank you ! I couldn't spot him in the preview and I may have been overwhelmed over the thought of Ghost being dead !

Comment: He was kicking butt, but the darkness known as "CGI Budget" obscured it from your view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## He lives

You can see him in the preview for Episode 4 to the right of Dany in the below picture.

[image]

Comment: I kind of feel like I'm blind and ghost looks like a goat.. but I'll take it ! Thank you !

Comment: @Anu7 https://youtu.be/ksTqLXLUvQ4?list=TLGGqxNLnKOEKCAyOTA0MjAxOQ&t=18